# Usando opção única com radio button

Tags: html

Não estou conseguindo criar uma opção única para seleção via radio-button. Quando clico em duas opções, ele seleciona as duas, quando o ideal seria ou uma ou outra.

```html
   <div><label for="b_ant">Base Anterior</label><input name="b_ant" type="radio" value="S" /></div>
   <div><label for="b_grade">Base na Grade</label><input name="b_grade" type="radio" value="S" /></div>
   <div><label for="b_grade">Base em Veículos Novos</label><input name="b_novos" type="radio" value="S" /></div>
```

Comment: os names devem ser iguais

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com HTML puro somente conforme consta no meu comentário na sua pergunta `os names devem ser iguais`

Quando uma opção RADIO é marcada, esta só será desmarcada quando outra opção RADIO **com mesmo NAME** for selecionada

Se for necessário manter os names diferentes, considere usar jquery. exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label for="b_ant">Base Anterior</label><input name="b_ant" type="radio" value="S" /></div>
   <div><label for="b_grade">Base na Grade</label><input name="b_grade" type="radio" value="S" /></div>
   <div><label for="b_grade">Base em Veículos Novos</label><input name="b_novos" type="radio" value="S" /></div>
```

> [**not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/)  seleciona todos os elementos, exceto o elemento especificado.
>
> [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) `prop('checked', false)` usado para desmarcar.
>
> `not(this).prop('checked', false);` vai desmarcar todos os inputs radios exceto o selecionado

Comment: Conseguiria dar um exemplo de quando seria necessário ter vários elementos *radio* que representam o mesmo campo, porém com nomes distintos?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, não é o foco do post avaliar uma ou outra situação, estou apenas respondendo a uma pergunta. Isto vc deve perguntar ao autor do post.

Comment: É que como sugeriu a solução, achei que saberia, mas obrigado.

Comment: É como eu disse na resposta - Se for necessário manter os names diferentes - o uso te tal situação só o AP pode explicar. Entendo que você fez essa pergunta inadequadamente com segundas intenções.

Answer (score 9):

O name dos inputs devem ser o mesmo. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<div>
  <label>
    Base Anterior
    <input id="ant" name="base" type="radio" value="S" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Base na Grade
    <input id="grade" name="base" type="radio" value="S" />
  </label>  
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Base em Veículos Novos
    <input id="novo" name="base" type="radio" value="S" />
  </label>
</div>
```